# How to combine 2 list of objects with no duplicates?

Tags: groovy

I have 2 groovy sql resultset, I need to combine the result set so that `project_no` should be unique and `case_no` can have multiple elements if there is a duplicate `project_no`

Below are the 2 groovy sql resultset

```
[[project_no:0-10001,case_no:00492268],[project_no:0-10160,case_no:01957580],[project_no:1-10014,case_no:02022686]]

[[project_no:0-10160,case_no:01957590],[project_no:1-10014,case_no:019126],[project_no:1-2896337,case_no:02039596]]
```

Desired List

```
[[project_no:0-10001,case_nos:[00492268]], [project_no:0-10160,case_nos:[01957580,01957590]] ,[project_no:1-10014,case_nos:[02022686,019126]], [project_no:1-2896337,case_nos:[02039596]]]
```

This is what I have tried

```
caseResultForAnalysis.each { ca ->
    def ptmp = [:], caseList = []
    tempPrList.add(ca["project_no"])
    ptmp["project_no"] = ca["project_no"]
    caseList.add(ca["case_no"])
    if (caseList.size() > 0) {
        ptmp["case_nos"] = caseList
        mergedCaseResult.push(ptmp)
    }
}
mergedCaseResult.each { ma ->
    def ptmp = [:], caseList = []
    caseResultForUploads.each { cp ->
        if (!tempPrList.contains(cp["project_no"])) {
            ptmp["project_no"] = ma["project_no"]
            caseList.add(cp["case_no"])
        } else if (ma["project_no"] == cp["project_no"]) {
            //if (!ma["case_nos"].contains(cp["case_no"]))
            List tmp = ma["case_nos"]
            if (!tmp.contains(cp["case_no"]))
                ma["case_nos"].add(cp["case_no"])
        }
    }
    if (caseList.size() > 0) {
        ptmp["case_nos"] = caseList
        mergedCaseResult.push(ptmp)
    }
}

//1st list caseResultForAnalysis
//2nd List caseResultForUploads
//desired List mergedCaseResult
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this can be more groovified.

Here is the script which does what OP is needed.

```
def list1 = [[project_no:'0-10001',case_no:'00492268'],[project_no:'0-10160',case_no:'01957580'],[project_no:'1-10014',case_no:'02022686']]
def list2 = [[project_no:'0-10160',case_no:'01957590'],[project_no:'1-10014',case_no:'019126'],[project_no:'1-2896337',case_no:'02039596']]

def result = list1+list2
def projNos = result.inject([]) { keys, item ->  keys << item.project_no } as Set


def finalResult = []
projNos.each { proj ->
    //To avoid duplicate cases in project, using it as Set
    def cases = [] as Set
    result.each { item ->
        if (item.project_no == proj) {
            cases << item.case_no
        }
    }
    finalResult << [ 'project_no': proj, 'case_no' : cases ]
}

println finalResult
```

You may quickly try online <kbd>[Demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5136464736157696)</kbd>

Comment: In case if there is a duplicate object in list1 and list2 it creates a `case_no` with duplicate case nos. `case_no:[1,1]`

Comment: Sorry did not get you. Do you have a sample?

Comment: Check this [demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5164021246328832) it will have duplicate case_no items

Comment: Sorry it last formatting add I edited from mobile. All you need to add to avoid duplicates is to have `def cases = [] as Set `

Comment: @Ricky, you can check the updated answer and see if that helps.

Comment: @Rao _"I'm sure this can be more groovified."_  Challenge accepted ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can make it a bit more "groovy" with:

```
def list1 = [[project_no:'0-10001',case_no:'00492268'],[project_no:'0-10160',case_no:'01957580'],[project_no:'1-10014',case_no:'02022686']]
def list2 = [[project_no:'0-10160',case_no:'01957590'],[project_no:'1-10014',case_no:'019126'],[project_no:'1-2896337',case_no:'02039596']]

def finalResult = (list1 + list2).groupBy { it.project_no }
                                 .collect { k, v -> [project_no:k, case_no:v.case_no.unique()] }
```

Comment: I know that I am a starter in groovy. You are an inspiration to improve my groovy skills, learning a lot from your invaluable replies(which are almost onliners in every possible case) and foundation for many of my groovy answers. Thank you so much.

Comment: How to keep only unique casenos per project_no? check [this demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5200424046952448)

Comment: @Rao Aww, thanks!  Keep going, it's only practice, and answering questions here is a brilliant way to practice and help people as almost a side effect :-D